# Create a random array of numbers excluding 0

Tags: javascript

I am trying to randomize numbers 1-6.

I have the following code already:

```
for (var a=[],i=0;i<6;++i) a[i]=i;
    function shuffle(array) {
        var tmp, current, top = array.length;
        if(top) while(--top) {
            current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
            tmp = array[current];
            array[current] = array[top];
            array[top] = tmp;
        }
        return array
    }
    a = shuffle(a);
    console.log(shuffle(a));
```

However, in my console this includes the number 0 and excludes 6.
Is there a way to make these numbers range from 1 - 6 instead of 0-5?

Comment: You can do something like this `for (var a=[],i=0;i<6;++i) a[i]=i+1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done

```
for (var a=[],i=0;i<6;++i)
a[i-1]=i;
```

Instead you could have done

```
for (var a=[],i=1;i<=6;++i)
a[i-1]=i;
```

Comment: this produces an "undefined" value in the console (presumably where 0 wants to be)

Comment: Or keep the loop as it is and `a[i]=i+1`

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
alert(random);
```

that should be

```
var temp = [];
for(i=0; i<=6; i++){

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
    temp[i] = random;
}

console.log(temp);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9ws311cv/3/)

Comment: @JqueryKing i'm afraid that creates duplicate numbers

Answer (score -1):

try following:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

plus one must be done after random ;)